# Выводит непонятные символы в printf

Tags: c

Требовалось реализовать парсинг строки, крутил так и эдак, всё время в консоль вместо нужных строк выводятся непонятные символы, при том что в дебаге всё отлично. В данном случае функция ищет подстроку, окружённую двойными кавычками, и возвращает ее без кавычек. Говнокод в функции потому, что отчаялся и ищу малейшую возможность реализации.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char* string;

string get_request(string next_line)
{
    char buffer[256];
    sprintf(buffer, "%s", next_line);

    size_t ptr_first_quotation = strcspn(buffer, "\"");
    if (ptr_first_quotation == strlen(buffer))
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    sprintf(buffer, "%s", buffer + ptr_first_quotation + 1);

    size_t ptr_second_quotation = strcspn(buffer, "\"");
    if (ptr_second_quotation == strlen(buffer))
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    
    char result[30];
    snprintf(result, 30, "%s", buffer);
    return result;
}
```

Пример вывода в консоль при входной строке

199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что на деле в дебаге: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: завершающий ноль в конце то есть ?

Comment: Да, по идее практически любая функция из string.h автоматически его добавляет, сейчас вручную ввёл -- без изменений.

Comment: у вас `result` - локальный, когда вы его начинаете использовать вне функции, объекта на который он ссылается уже может и не существовать

Comment: @Optimus1 Функция snprintf переводит 29 символов из buffer, 30-й делает нулем

Comment: @Камиль Муталов, в каком участке кода вы выводите данные из result на консоль?

Comment: @Optimus1 В мэйне

Comment: @Камиль Муталов, создайте в мейне reuslt и передайте указатель на result в функцию.  Мне любопытно, а зачем вот это запись нужна - typedef char* string ? Что за сакральный смысл ?

Comment: @Optimus1 Спасибо) а тайпдеф из-за величайшей ненависти к Си

Comment: Видимо лишь очевидная ненависть к Си заставляет несколько раз бессмысленно копировать одно и то же. Копировать вообще не надо. Надо же, используя [strchr](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html), найти первый и следующий за ним символы `"` прямо в аргументе функции и (если p1 указатель на первый, а p2 на второй) завершить ее `return strndup(p1 + 1, p2 - p1 - 1);`

Comment: @avp Спасибо за решение, я даже не знал про эти функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char result[30];
snprintf(result, 30, "%s", buffer);
return result;
```

Я правильно понял, что вы возвращаете указатель на буфер, который локальный и по завершению функции вроде как должен сдохнуть?

Comment: Точно. А как тогда его вернуть?

Comment: например, выделить память и вернуть указатель  (c++ - `new`, а в `c` - всякие `alloc` и т.п.) - только не забыть потом где-то освободить память

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А не подскажете, как очистить память, выделенную в другой функции, если после return просто по имени обратиться к динамическому массиву?

Comment: Все, теперь понял